# How can I validate the integrity of a torrent retrieved through DHT?

Tags: checksum, bittorrent, verification

I've just downloaded a dataset made available through BitTorrent and (at length) transferred it to my home PC.

Now I want to validate that nothing's been corrupted along the way.

Unfortunately, the source of the dataset only provides magnet hashes, not .torrent files - which I've learned is where the checksum information is.

Is there a way I can look up a particular magnet link in DHT, retrieve the metadata for the torrent from the BT network, and save said metadata into a .torrent file so I can then use it for local verification?

I realize I could also just fire up a BitTorrent client on my home internet connection, but I've heard too many scary stories involving legitimate/scientific/etc data and lawyers etc to want to do that. (Long-tail/edge-case FUD, maybe, but still.)

(FWIW, OpenVPN/WireGuard and then locally-based BitTorrent are squarely on the agenda once I master per-process default routing on Linux.)

Comment: Your original torrent client probably has an option to save a torrent file. If not, use a client which does ([Deluge does](https://dev.deluge-torrent.org/ticket/2161)).

Comment: Ah, I thought qBittorrent lacked this functionality. There appears to be some discussion around surfacing an explicit option, but currently it buries .torrent files in the filesystem.

Comment: And it works! `torrentcheck` was able to work with the torrent file just fine. @muru: You can turn your comment into an answer if you want.

Comment: It might be better if you posted an answer, showing how you configured qbittorent to save torrent files, or where you found them if it already saved those.